# Black rice mixed in white

Tags: rice

In the long grain white rice (parboiled) there these occasional grains of darker brown to black grains. Any idea what these are?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are grains of rice that have not been polished. Rice comes in many colors. The outer hull needs removed like wheat. Then to mids or inner skin polished off. The mids is were the oil is. If not removed rice will go rancid in 3 to 4 months. They will not harm you.

Comment: The black grains are far smaller, and likely fall through the rollers used to polish white rice. Likely they're a different kind of rice. Several types invade fields: https://howtocookaweed.com/tag/black-rice/  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weedy_rice  If you are unlucky they'll take far longer to cook than the polished white stuff.

Comment: "If not removed rice will go rancid in 3 to 4 months." It'll also be more nutritious, though.